# join time series NA values using Pandas

Tags: pandas

How can I add NA's from input2 to input1 col1 values using the date as index?

input1

```
                 col1
2020-02-01 00:00:00 0
2020-02-01 00:01:00 0
2020-02-01 00:02:00 0
2020-02-01 00:03:00 0
2020-02-01 00:04:00 0
2020-02-03 00:02:00 0
2020-02-04 00:03:00 0
2020-02-05 00:04:00 0
```

input2

```
2020-02-03 NaN
2020-02-04 NaN
```

output

```
                 col1
2020-02-01 00:00:00 0
2020-02-01 00:01:00 0
2020-02-01 00:02:00 0
2020-02-01 00:03:00 0
2020-02-01 00:04:00 0
2020-02-03 00:02:00 NaN
2020-02-04 00:03:00 NaN
2020-02-04 00:04:00 NaN
2020-02-05 00:04:00 0
```

Comment: There is no data for 'input1' for '2020-02-04 00:04:00'. What is the reason for adding this to the output?

Comment: Yes there is. col1 has all zeroes.

Comment: `df1.loc[np.isin(df1.index.date, df2.date.tolist()), 'col'] = np.nan` ? https://webruntime.netlify.app/#/Google_108617488638529745626/python/c36f45f7.py

Comment: yes. post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` if performance is a concern, but for simplicity you can also leverage boolean index for conditional assignment:

Say you have `df1`, `df2` created as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# prepare the data
data = [["2020-02-01 00:00:00", 0 ],
["2020-02-01 00:01:00", 0 ],
["2020-02-01 00:02:00", 0 ],
["2020-02-01 00:03:00", 0 ],
["2020-02-01 00:04:00", 0 ],
["2020-02-03 00:02:00", 0 ],
["2020-02-04 00:03:00", 0 ],
["2020-02-05 00:04:00", 0 ]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['datetime', 'col'])
df1['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.datetime)
df1.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2020-02-03', None],
    ['2020-02-04', None]], 
columns=['date', 'col'])
df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df2.date).dt.date
```

Then the following should work:

```
df1.loc[np.isin(df1.index.date, df2.date.tolist()), 'col'] = np.nan
print(df1)

#                      col
#datetime                
#2020-02-01 00:00:00  0.0
#2020-02-01 00:01:00  0.0
#2020-02-01 00:02:00  0.0
#2020-02-01 00:03:00  0.0
#2020-02-01 00:04:00  0.0
#2020-02-03 00:02:00  NaN
#2020-02-04 00:03:00  NaN
#2020-02-05 00:04:00  0.0
```

You can play around with [the solution here](https://webruntime.netlify.app/#/Google_108617488638529745626/python/c36f45f7.py).